# Any good example of Nativescript (Angular) + aws-amplify

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, nativescript-angular

Any good example of developing mobile app with Nativescript (Angular) with aws-amplify (IAmUser pool)? Also further integration of Api gateway with Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get aws-amplify angular libraries working in nativescript, so resorted to installing amplify's android packages in App_Resources/Android project. Adding the implementations in the app.gradle and initializing Amplify in a java class in the android project. Guess I'll have to do the same for iOS, and have platform conditional code whenever I need to call these plugins.